# What's the error in following code?

Tags: r

I am trying to separate movies released before 1992 from a column 3 that contains year of release from a big data set. What's the error in the command?

```
> Movies0<-Movies[Movies[,3]<1992,]
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(Movies[, 3], 1992) : < not meaningful for factors
>
```

Comment: Try `Movies[as.numeric(as.character(Movies[,3])) < 1992, ]`.

Comment: Seems to me the error is in column class, switch to integers instead of factors

Comment: @nrussell I'm pretty sure that your comment solves the problem and I believe that you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably column 3 of your `Movies` object is a `factor` variable, although it may *appear* to be `numeric`/`integer`, and as the warning indicates, the `<` operator is not defined for `factor`s.

---

For example,

```
Df <- data.frame(
  NumericColumn = 1:10,
  FactorColumn = as.factor(1:10)
)
##
R> Df[Df[,2] < 5,]
#NumericColumn FactorColumn
#NA              NA         <NA>
#NA.1            NA         <NA>
#NA.2            NA         <NA>
# ...
#Warning message:
#In Ops.factor(Df[, 2], 5) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
##
R> Df[Df[,1] < 5,] # okay
##
R> Df[as.numeric(as.character(Df[,2])) < 5,] # okay
```

---

Looking at the source code,

```
R> Ops.factor
#function (e1, e2) 
#{
#  ok <- switch(.Generic, `==` = , `!=` = TRUE, FALSE)
#  if (!ok) {
#    warning(gettextf("%s not meaningful for factors", sQuote(.Generic)))
#    return(rep.int(NA, max(length(e1), if (!missing(e2)) length(e2))))
#  }
# ...
```

---

you can see which operators can be used with `factor`s, and `<` is not one of them.